# Updated Spring Boot from 2.0.0.RELEASE to 2.0.2.RELEASE broke the Spring Web?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm developing **Spring Boot Redis** example. I was using Spring Boot v `2.0.0.RELEASE` when I updated the dependency to `2.0.3.RELEASE` then `@RequestMapping` and `@PathVariable` got failed. What dependency do I need to add ?

Do I need to add any separate dependency ??

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Error

[image]

Dependency 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you use 2.0.3.RELEASE not 2.0.2.RELEASE?

Comment: RequestMapping and PathVariable are part of the spring-mvc project. I'm currently use 2.0.2 and don't have problem with this annotation. Did you try to rebuild project and clean cache?

Comment: change the version of spring boot starter parent to 2.0.3 @user

Comment: Attached the screen shot. Could you please make aware about the solution irrespective of 2.0.2 or 2.0.3 ?

Comment: current which version you are using 2.0.2 or 2.0.3 ? @Prateek